# Port mirroring on an HP Switch (HP 2915-8G)

Tags: hp, switching

for sniffing purposes I need to mirror traffic on an HP 2915. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Are you wanting to sniff packets and use a utility like Wireshark?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can certainly use Port Mirroring with the HP 2915.  You can find the information for port mirroring on page B-23 in the [documentation for the 2915](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02564193/c02564193.pdf).

You will be able to designate monitoring of inbound and outbound traffic on either individual ports, groups of ports, static port trunks, and one static VLAN.

An example to assign a port as the monitoring port:

> ProCurve(config)# mirror-port 8

Removing port 8 as the monitoring port:

> ProCurve(config)# no mirror-port

Once you assign the monitor port you can then select the source interfaces:

> ProCurve(config)# int 1-4, monitor

To show the current monitor (this will display what port is the monitor port, called the mirror port, and what the sources being monitored are)

> ProCurve(config)# show monitor

Answer (score 5):

A better term would be "port mirroring". This concept is generally universal among vendor products. (Cisco would call theirs SPAN, but it's essentially the same thing). You take a range of ports or VLANs, and simply copy all traffic to a destination port, where you'd hook up a PC with wireshark.

Try [this thread](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Switches-Hubs-Modems-Legacy-ITRC/port-mirroring/td-p/3685231#.Ue1Deo3vt30) - it's not a complete exhaustive walkthrough but it will point you in the right direction. Regardless, searching for terms like "HP Port Mirroring" should yield better results.